# Powershell script with Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter give error when launched in task scheduler

Tags: powershell

Script is working in powershell console but give error when run as scheduled task.

Error :

```
>         Get-ADObject : Le filtre de recherche n est pas reconnu
>     Au caractŠre \\get.com\netlogon\Powershell\ACTIVE_DIRECTORY\UPDATE_AD_PHONE.ps1:70
> : 7
>     +     if ((Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=$PRENOM)(Sn=$NOM))" | ...
>     +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADObject], ADException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject
```

Here is the line :

```
if ((Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=$PRENOM)(Sn=$NOM))" | ft -HideTableHeaders DistinguishedName | Out-String).Trim())
```

**EDIT:**
Part of the script. I can't upload full

```
$filepath = "c:\liste\Liste telephonique.csv"
# Les champs (on lit le fichier à partir de la ligne 3)
# NOM;Prénom;SITE;"N° Mobile";"Abrégé";"N° Direct";;;;;;;;
$File = Get-Content -Path $filepath | Select-Object -Skip 3 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
Foreach($Ligne in $File)
    {
    $NOM = $Ligne."NOM"
    $PRENOM = $Ligne."Prénom"
    
    # On cherche dans AD si le couple NOM/PRENOM nous retourne un DN
    # Si oui on continue, sinon on quitte la ligne.
    if ((Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(givenName=$PRENOM)(sn=$NOM))" | ft -HideTableHeaders DistinguishedName | Out-String).Trim()) 
        {
        $DN = (Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(givenName=$PRENOM)(sn=$NOM))" | ft -HideTableHeaders DistinguishedName | Out-String).Trim() 
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2 :**

```
NOM;PRENOM;PLACE;;1028;
NOM;PRENOM;PLACE;0x-xx-xx-xx-xx;;
```

Comment: Try with correct LDAP spelling: `"(&(givenName=$PRENOM)(sn=$NOM))"` and show us what variables `$PRENOM` and `$NOM` contain exactly because some characters may need escaping with a backslash. Also, did you save the UPDATE_AD_PHONE.ps1 file in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: spelling modified but still no luck. Variables are strings. Ex : $PRENOM=Alex and $NOM=Rock, variable init : $NOM = $Ligne."NOM" , $PRENOM = $Ligne."Prénom". File is already encoded as UTF8. I can't upload full script.

Comment: Do you get the same error when (for test) hardcode the values like `"(&(givenName=Alex)(sn=Rock))"`? Otherwise try to determine on what csv input the command complains by adding a Write-Host "Firstname: $PRENOM   LastName: $NOM". How are you reading the input CSV file? Is that file UTF-8 encoded? Do you use the correct delimiter character when importing? Does your input csv file have empty fields? PLease update the post and show us what that looks like as formatted text. Copy the first 3 or 4 lines, sanitize the user names and add it to the question.

Comment: No error with hardcoded arguments ("(&(givenName=Alex)(sn=Rock))"). So what do i need to make it work with task scheduler? I will try to encode csv in UTF8 and let you know.

Comment: $filepath = "c:\liste\Liste telephonique .csv" (Get-Content -Path $filepath) | Set-Content -Path $filepath -Encoding UTF8 $File = Get-Content -Path $filepath | Select-Object -Skip 3 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' . Same error with UTF8 encoded. Delimiter is OK. input csv can have empty fields. ok i will update post.

Comment: ERRATUM : $PRENOM = $Ligne."Prénom" does not produce output when run in task scheduler. have i to escape "é"?

Comment: Although it is never a good idea to have accented characters in csv headers, this means your csv file is not saved in utf8 format, or it is in utf8 without BOM. Please try with `Import-Csv -Path 'c:\liste\Liste telephonique .csv' -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8`. If as you say the file _can_ have empty fields, you should add a test before using a $null value in the LDAP filter

Comment: I ve just tested without accented characters and it work now. "Although it is never a good idea to have accented characters in csv headers" >>> Thank you very much @Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using accented characters in the input CSV file, it is vital you save this in UTF8 encoding.
Also the script itself should be in UTF8 and looking at the error message where it says `caractŠre`, this is not the case here..

After you have made sure both files are in utf8 encoding below code should work:

```
$filepath = "c:\liste\Liste telephonique.csv"
# Les champs (on lit le fichier à partir de la ligne 3)
# NOM;Prénom;SITE;"N° Mobile";"Abrégé";"N° Direct";;;;;;;;
$File = Import-Csv -Path $filepath -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
foreach($Ligne in $File) {
    $NOM    = $Ligne."NOM"
    $PRENOM = $Ligne."Prénom"

    # On cherche dans AD si le couple NOM/PRENOM nous retourne un DN
    # Si oui on continue, sinon on quitte la ligne.

    # don't use Format-* cmdlets if you want to process using its properties
    # Format-* cmdlets are for display purposes ONLY
    $adObject = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(givenName=$PRENOM)(sn=$NOM))" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adObject) {
        # proceed with the code once you have found the object
        $DN = $adObject.DistinguishedName

        # using names as search filters however CAN result in multiple objects being found
        # so you may consider processing in another loop like
        # $adObject | ForEach-Object {
        #     $DN = $_.DistinguishedName
        #     # process this object
        # }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find object using NOM:'$NOM'  Prénom: '$PRENOM'.."
    }
}
```